# Emgu CV Video Source Popup

Tags: opencv, video, emgucv

Using EmguCV 2.4.2 I am getting a "Video Source" popup which prompts me to select a video device after instantiating a new instance of `Emgu.CV.Capture`. With earlier versions of EmguCV the constructor for `Emgu.CV.Capture` respected the `camIndex` parameter and activated the appropriate camera without further user interaction. This is pretty critical for my application where the user is not (and should not) be involved in the camera selection process.

The relevant code is below:

```
var capture = new Emgu.CV.Capture(0);
```

Right after that line is called, the windows dialog pops up asking to pick the video device.

Has anyone else seen this and come up with a solution?

Thanks in advance.

**Edit 06/16/2014 @ 4:56PM CST**

I was able to get to a more meaningful error message under the covers. Basically what was happening is OpenCV was unable to create the Capture instance using camIndex 0. As a result, it was popping up the select video source dialog.

I was able to get this error message in version 2.9.0, version 2.4.2 and version 2.4.0. All of those versions give me an error “Error: Unable to create capture from camera 0”.

The only version that works with this device is version 2.3.1 and that is the version that does not allow me to change the resolution of the Capture instance.